# Cargar datos en un Dropdown List y obtener ID Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dropdownlist

Buen día, tengo un dropdown list, que debe mostrar una lista de nombres, traídos desde el servidor, esta lista JSON que me devuelve el servidor, me da el `UserID` y el `Name`, en el dropdown debe mostrar `Name`, pero quisiera que al seleccionar ese dato, pueda obtener el `UserID`, para un proceso sucesivo.

Tengo el código del modelo:

```
class GetUsers {
    GetUsers({
        required this.userId,
        required this.name,
    });

    int userId;
    String name;

    factory GetUsers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetUsers(
        userId: json["UserID"],
        name: json["Name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "UserID": userId,
        "Name": name,
    };
```

El código que carga la información:

```
//FUNCIÓN QUE OBTIENE Y MUESTRA LOS DATOS DE LOS USUARIOS EN EL DROPDOWN LIST.
  Future<void> fetchAndShow() async {
    final users = await getData();
    final usersid =await getData();
    setState(() {
      this.users = users ?? [];
      this.users = usersid ?? [];
    });
  }
```

Y el código del dropdown, donde no he podido obtener el `UserID`:

```
                  DropdownButton<GetUsers>(
                    value: selected,
                    onChanged: (GetUsers? newValue) {
                      // here you'll get selected value
                      setState(() {
                        selected = newValue!;
                        newuserid = items.indexWhere((element) => e.userid); // prueba
                      });
                    },
                    items: users.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(e.name), 
                            value: e,),).toList(),
                  ),
```

Y el código del botón que va a hacer el proceso siguiente, que es obtener una fecha de un DatePicker que tengo implementado y funcionando, y el obtener el `UserID`, nótese que intenté usar un indexOf // indexWhere para el proceso, pero no resuelve mi problema en particular.

```
              TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: AppTheme.primary,
                      primary: Colors.white, //TEXT COLOR
                      minimumSize: const Size(120, 50) //TAMANO - WH
                      ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                   
                    var finalUserID = newuserid;
                    var finalRecordTypeID = 1;
                    var finalRecordDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);
                    futureQueryRecordAdmin = fetchQueryRecordAdmin(finalUserID, finalRecordDate, finalRecordTypeID);
                    debugPrint(finalUserID.toString() + finalRecordDate + finalRecordTypeID.toString());
                    
                  },
                  child: const Text('queryrecords.apply').tr()),
```

Cualquier sugerencia o solución al problema, lo agradeceré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizo la propiedad onTap, lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
    DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selected = newValue!;
                  });
                },
           value: selected,
           hint: Text("Seleccione una jornada",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
           ),
         },
         items: users.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  onTap:(){
                    setState(() {
                      //CREA UNA VARIABLE DE CLASE DEL ID
                      userId = item.userId;
                    });
                  }
                  child: Text(item.name), 
                  value: item.name,),).toList(),
                  ),
```

Espero y eso te funcione.

Comment: Dice que la función onChanged es requerida.

Comment: Supongo que es debido a que yo utilizo el DropdownButton como <GetUsers>.

Comment: Es cierto, fue fallo mio, tienes que usar el onChanged para poder actualizar el valor del combo, por otro lado el onTap del DropdownMenuItem va a seleccionar el valor de la lista de personas que se presentan en el combo

Comment: Actualicé el código

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona gracias a tu solución, solo que, lo dejé solo como ```DropdownButton```, quitando el ```FormField``` por cuestiones del diseño. Y cambié ```String``` por ```GetUsers```, lo demás funcionó muy bien. gracias